# Cannot keep certain numbers from averaging

Tags: python-3.x

I need help. I'm trying to run the program below. When I enter a number above 100 or below 0 I need it to disregard that input any advice?

```
total = 0.0
count = 0
data = int(input("Enter a number or 999 to quit: "))
while data != "":
    count += 1
    number = float(data)
    total += number
    data = int(input("Enter a number or 999 to quit: "))
    try:
        data = int(data)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    average = round(total) / count
    if data == 999:
        break
    elif data >= 100:
        print("error in value")
    elif data <= 0:
        number = 0
        print("error in value")   


print("These", count, "scores average as: ", round(average, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `average = ...` line behind the checking for invalid numbers and add `continue` to the checks for invalid numbers. So the last lines would end up like this:

```
    if data == 999:
        break
    elif data >= 100:
        print("error in value")
        continue
    elif data <= 0:
        print("error in value")
        continue
    average = round(total) / count
```